# Choosing a ball randomly from each urn

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am stucked at this combinatorics/probability problem:

---

There are 10 urns, each contains 8 balls numbered 1,2,...,8

If we randomly choose 1 ball from **each** urn, what is the probability that the **total** number of 1's will be **exactly** 3 and the **total** number of 4's will be **exactly** 2 ?

---

I have tried several times to solve this problem but I got incorrect probabilities.

Thanks for any hint/help.

Comment: Hint: group the balls into 3 categories: 1's, 4's, and the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ denote the number of $1$'s, let $Y$ denote the number of $4$'s and let let $Z$ denote the number of other numbers. Then:$$P(X=3\wedge Y=2\wedge Z=5)=\frac{10!}{3!2!5!}\left(\frac18\right)^3\left(\frac18\right)^2\left(\frac68\right)^5$$

First a selection concerning: from wich urn are the $1$'s, $4$'s and others taken? There are $\frac{10!}{3!2!5!}$ possibilities for that. Then the question: by a fixed selection what is the probability that this indeed happens? It is $\left(\frac18\right)^3\left(\frac18\right)^2\left(\frac68\right)^5$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It is the Multinomial Distribution.

Comment: Indeed it is! I first misread the number of urns (I thought it were $8$) but now repaired.

Answer (score 3):

First you choose $10-3-2=5$ urns out which are neither $1$ nor $4$ $(C^{10}_5\times6^5)$
Among the remaining $5$ choose $3$ out, which are the $1$'s $(C^5_3)$
The remaining 2 will be the $4$'s
Number of ways satisfying the conditions $=C^{10}_5\times6^5\times C^5_3$
Total number of ways $=8^{10}$
To find the probability you just divides them.

Answer (score 2):

Select 3 out of 10 urns for 1's. Then 2 out of remaining 7 urns for 4's:

$$\binom{10}{3}\binom{7}{2}\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^3\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^2\left(1-\frac{2}{8}\right)^5=\frac{76545}{4194304}\approx 0.0183$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the multinomial distribution formula as there are **3 categories (1's,4's and the rest)**

Pr = $\dfrac{10!}{3!2!5!} \times  \left(\dfrac{1}{8}\right)^3\times\left(\dfrac{1}{8}\right)^2\times\left(\dfrac{6}{8}\right)^5$

Its parallel to the binomial distribution should be obvious.