# Is Binomial distribution applicable if the event is different but probability of success same?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

One can apply Binomial distribution if, `p` probability of success is constant for all events that are independent. However, if `p` is the same but the events differ then is it still applicable?

Example; Typical elementary questions on this ask ;

> What is the probability that exactly 3 four's will show up if a die is rolled 6 times

Q1) Given each face has equal probability. Is Binominal distribution still applicable if the event changes but `p` is the same?
Example: 1 four , 1 six , 1 five if the  die is rolled 6 times?

Q2) if `p` is different for some events. So `p1` `p2`. Is there any way to split it and combine?
Example: An exam has 3 - single choice question (SCQ. p1=0.25) and 4 - MCQs (p2 = 0.1). What is the probability we get 2 SCQ right and 1 MCQ right?

Comment: For Q1, how can you have only $3$ outcomes when you are rolling a die $6$ times ?

Comment: the word exactly refers to the number of desired outcomes, not total. The question is asking if the die is rolled 6 times; then within that one gets 3 desired outcomes. The rest of the 3 times can be any other event that we are not interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Q1

This is known as a [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) From your clarification, it is clear that you can divide the outcomes into getting $4,5,6$, and any other three with probabilities of $\frac16,\frac16,\frac16,\; and\; \frac36$ respectively

Instead of the *binomial* coefficient, you will have the *multinomial* coefficient $\large\binom{6}{1,1,1,3} = \large\frac{6!}{1!1!1!3!}$

The formula will then be $\frac{6!}{1!1!1!3!}\cdot(\frac1 6)^3(\frac3 6)^3$

Q2

Yes you can use the binomial distribution for the two parts. Since now there are two separate Bernoulli trials, and you want the *Pr* of 2 SCQ right **and** 1 MCQ right, and the two trials are independent,

$Pr = [\binom32*0.25^2*0.75^1]*[\binom41(0.1^1)(0.9^3)]$

Comment: For Q2, earlier you said add, but I think you edited to multiply (**and**); which makes sense now. For Q1 , am researching to be convinced.

Comment: @ArjunDhar: Re Q1, you can have a look at my answer (and those of others) to a parallel problem some $7$ years ago. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361766/choosing-a-ball-randomly-from-each-urn/1361799#1361799